# How to add jstree via webpacker to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jstree, webpacker

I have a Rails 6 app where I added `jstree` library via yarn. I have `application.js` file where are the `require` statement. I want to do the following
`$('#tree').jstree();` but this results in `function jstree undefined` exception. How should I require it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new Rails app:

```
rails new myapp
cd myapp
```

Install jstree and jQuery (which it depends upon):

```
yarn add jstree jquery
```

Create a new controller and view:

```
rails g controller welcome index
```

Start the dev server and the Rails server:

```
./bin/webpack-dev-server
rails s
```

In `packs/application.js`:

```js
require('../../../node_modules/jstree/dist/themes/default/style.min.css');
global.$ = require('jquery');
require('jstree');

$(() => {
  $('#jstree').jstree();
});
```

Add some HTML to `welcome#index`:

```html
<div id="jstree">
  <ul>
    <li>Root node 1
      <ul>
        <li id="child_node_1">Child node 1</li>
        <li>Child node 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Root node 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Visit http://localhost:3000/welcome/index to see jstree in action.

HTH

Comment: Thanks James for a in-depth response. `Still getting the following error: application.js:39 Uncaught TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...)(...).jstree is not a function`

Comment: `require('../../../node_modules/jstree/dist/themes/default/style.min.css');
global.$ = require("jquery");
require('jstree');
global.jQuery = global.$;

$(() => {
    $('#jstree').jstree();
  });`

Comment: So, what I posted above works, but when you try and implement it in your app, you get an error. Did I get that right?

Comment: Yes, absolutely

Comment: Ok, if you can make a bare bones example (strip out everything apart from what is necessary to recreate the error), stick it up on GitHub and let me have a link to a repo, I'll take a look.

Comment: Actually, I can't as this is a commercial app. I tried to extend the jquery functions but it is not working...

Comment: My only other suggestion would be to add jQuery to your webpack config like so: https://joey.io/how-to-use-jquery-in-rails-5-2-using-webpack/